# Tools to decode SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have many certificates with different extensions (.pem, .crt, .der, .p7b).

Is OpenSSL capable of decoding all types of certificates (files with different extensions) or does it only decode some file extensions?

Comment: No tool is going to decode my made up certificate file. Be specific about what you really mean, what you expect and what you're facing.

Comment: When you say decode the certificate what do you mean?

Comment: `openssl` can decode many certificates in files with different extensions (note that files with the same extension can contain different kinds of certificates), but it will need different command line arguments for that. If you can define what you mean by "all types of" by giving a complete list (there are more certificate types than you think), we can at least try to compare to that list.

Comment: I don't have a list but I have SSL certificates with different extensions , I wanted to make sure if OpenSSL will be capabl of decoding them

Comment: The first three are the same type...